# Java - Trigger swing timer with a mouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouseevent

I'm trying to turn on the timer using mouseEntered event with MouseListener it doesn't seem to work. Am i doing somthing wrong? I'm new to Java. Thanks in advance!

```
int counter = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer(1000,this);
public void mouseEntered(e MouseEvent)
{ 
    if(e.getComponent == mouseEnteredArea) 
    {
       timer.start()
       counter++;
       if(counter == 10)
       {
          timer.stop();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(e.getComponent == mouseEnteredArea)` This line makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is when the mouse enters the area, your code starts the timer, adds one to counter (so counter == 1), checks if counter is equal to 10. Since it isn't, the code then skips the if statement and exits the method.

It's difficult to tell your actual intentions from that question, so if that wasn't enough to help, please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer anything, please post information or requests in a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @user1803551 "You must have 50 reputation to comment". I would have if I could have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not understand how the timer works. Basically the timer has an `ActionListener`. Every 1000 milliseconds (in your case), the `actionPerformed` will be called. So I believe the code you have above should be in the `ActionListener`, and just call `timer.start()` in the mouse method. Something like.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    private int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (counter == 10) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Count: " + (++counter));
        }
    }
});
....
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    timer.start();
}
```

**Resources**

- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)